# Transferring files between Windows Servers using shutil copy/move

Tags: python, windows

I am using shutil.copy() to transfer files from one server to another server on a network, both Windows.

I have used shutil and os modules for lot of automation tasks but confined to local machine. Are there better approaches to transfer file (I mean in terms of performance) from one server to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: use FTP, or in Python, [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html).

ETA: If it needs to be Secure File Transfer Protocol, [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) is a great library to use.

Answer (score 1):

*for lot of automation tasks but confined to local machine* use **fabric**